# Designing Ansible structure and variables

Tags: ansible

I've been playing around with Ansible for the last few weeks, trying to start moving over a set of bash scripts which we currently use for coldstarting/provisioning.  I've looked at repositories in Galaxy, but there are a lot of roles that don't seem to fit my example, so they're harder to learn from.  Anyway,t he way our inventory works is that we have a bunch of hosts who get approximately 75% the same roles.  However, there are a lot of decisions to be made based on a variable concerning that specific host.  An easy example is, we will want to write a role to install some certain software only if that host/inventory has a certain piece of hardware.  Other than hardware, we have to run specific roles/playbooks based on either the hostname or more preferably, some kind of organization with some variable like "does this host need X feature", where X is just some arbitrary pre-determined thing.  So I figured we could have a lot of groups, where an inventory group is like: "has_x_hardware" or "needs_x_software", and then list all the hosts that have that hardware.  But I can see that blowing up into a ton of groups with hosts repeated over and over and over again, and I don't think that's how this tool was supposed to be used.

An easy example to show what I'm working with, is that a lot of the bash scripts I'm trying to convert will like this:

`if [ "${hostname}" = "hostname1" ] ||
   [ "${hostname}" = "hostname2" ] ||
...
   [ "$(hostname)" = "hostnamex" ; then
     install_software_feature_X
fi`

Now how do I convert that without saying:

`when:
 some_hostname == hostname1 or some_hostname == hostname2`

But that seems like it will get out of control.

So I know this is kind of a general email with few *specifc* questions, but I'm not sure whether to have hostname/inventory based variables, where each hostname has a big group of variables, or to try and create variables based on groups, but the problem is we don't have just a few groups like "database", or "load balancer", where all database hosts or all load balancers get the same software.  Our hosts have lots of variables/decisions (does it have X, Y, and/or Z hardware, does it need software X, Y, and Z?) How does an organization deal with all of these variables that are more complicated than having a few groups and setting  up all of those groups the same.  I'm mostly asking the question: am I looking at this problem all wrong, am I missing something big? What best practices should I follow that makes my task a bit easier.

Thanks a lot for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is pretty much easy to understand, please read the Ansible recommended layout [ansible recommended layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout).

Variables can be defined in inventory, playbook, roles, etc..
[variables-defined-in-inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-inventory)

Just an example:

```
playbook-foobar/
├── ansible.cfg
├── requirements.yml
├── roles/nginx
├── inventories
│   ├── development
│   |   ├── group_vars
│   |   │   └── all
│   |   └── hosts
│   └── production
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all
│       └── hosts    
├── site.yml
└── playbooks
    ├── web.yml
```

Example:

```
ansible-playbook -i environments/development/hosts playbooks/web.yml --extra-vars "target=web" --flush-cache
```

hosts file:

```
[web]
web1 ansible_ssh_host=52.0.0.1
web2 ansible_ssh_host=52.0.0.2

[database]
db1 ansible_ssh_host=52.0.0.3
```

web.yml

```
---
- hosts: '{{ target }}'
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  roles:
      - { role: 'nginx', tags: 'nginx', gather_facts: True, become: yes, become_user: root, become_method: sudo }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I will mark it when I can.  I have read as much documentation as I can about best practices, but I must be missing something.  In the example you posted, does all the inventory get nginx? If not, what is best practice to specify that? Is playbook-foobar solely responsible for installing nginx, or is that just a role for that playbook? If that playbook also installs httpd, how is it specified which inventory gets that task?

Comment: I update the answer with example, there is many ways, so this is just one example, let me know if it is clear, but you need to play with this a bit and read/learn.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Playing with it a bit has led me to questions like this...if each hostname or inventory group has 2 variables, it doesn't seem so bad...but when I have 50 variables for a given host to decide which software to install, how do you specify that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what do you need, is it vars for inventories, roles, playbook ?

Comment: Well they are used in playbooks and roles, but the variables are relayed to the inventory and hostnames and groups.  I assume it's not correct to have groups like "'needs ssh", "needs nginx", "needs httpd", and have each hostname listed a bunch of times (once per group which feature it needs).  So the variables are tied directly to the hostname...for example, hostname1 will always need these 30 pieces of software, but hostname 2 will also need 20 of those pieces of software.  How do you specify which roles/playbooks apply to which inventory without having crazy when statements.

Comment: To keep it simple, I have a simple playbook which installs and configures redis.  10 of my hosts need redis, and 10 don't.  How do you specify that without having a "when" statement with 20 hostnames? And if the answer is "have two groups, what do you do with the next feature? Does that make sense or am I still off the mark? I realize I'm a beginner, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: you could do something like the example I wrote above, you run the playbook on the hosts file and specify the redis group of hosts

Comment: please also read `http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html`

Comment: So if there is a redis group in the inventory, there has to be a group for the other 50 pieces that make up a PC...is that how the inventory groups should be setup?

Comment: you can create more then one group on the environment hosts file (redis/blabla/kookoo) see the last link (you can use dynamic inventory if you running on aws for example).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to explain this to me.  I guess I just don't understand it.  I will have to try to read more tutorials and find one that fits my situation a bit better.

Comment: you are welcome, thats the basic (will be nice some upvote :) if it help a bit )